# How terminate this loop after a a given number of attempts?

Tags: python

For the most part it seems to be working, but not how I'm trying to get it to work. When I run it I am allowed unlimited tries to guess every single letter in the word until I spell out the word.

But that's not what I am going for, I'm trying to give the users 5 guesses with single letters if the letter is in the word then it will tell them "Yes", there is a(n) (users guess) in my word, but if the letter is not in my word then it will tell them "No", there is not a(n) (users guess) in my word.

After 5 attempt's at guessing different letters I want them to have to guess the full word but I can't figure out how.

This is what I have now:

```
import random

def get_word():
    words = ['cat', 'dog', 'man', 'fox', 'jar']
    return random.choice(words).upper()

def check(word,guesses,guess):
    status = ''
    matches = 0
    for letter in word:
        if letter in guesses:
            status += letter
        else:
            status += '*'
        if letter == guess:
            matches += 1

    count = 0
    limit = 5

    if matches > 1:
        print ('Yes! there is a(n)',guess,' in my word.')
        guesses += guess
    elif matches ==1:
        print ('Yes! there is a(n)',guess,' in my word.')
        guesses += guess
        while count > limit:
            input('What do you think my word is')
    else:
        print('No, there is not a(n)',guess,' in my word.')
        guesses += guess
        while count > limit:
            input('What do you think my word is')

    return status


def main():
    word = get_word()
    guesses = ""
    guessed = False
    print ('I am thinking of a 3 letter word with no repeating letters. You get five guesses of the letters in my word and then you have to guess the word.')
    while not guessed:
        text = 'Guess a letter in my word:'
        guess = input(text)
        guess = guess.upper()
        count = 0
        limit = 5
        if guess in guesses:
            print ('You already guessed "' + guess + '"')
        elif len(guess) == len(word):
            guesses += guess
            if guess == word:
                guessed = True
            else:
                print('No, there is not a(n) "' + guess + '"')
        elif len(guess) == 1:
            guesses += guess
            result = check(word,guesses,guess)
            if result == word:
                guessed = True

            else:
                print (result)

        else:
            print ('Invalid entry.')

    print ('Yes! you correctly guessed')

main()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please paste your code into the question and do not link to external sites.

Comment: You set `count = 0` every time through the loop, and never increment it.

Comment: And `count = 0` again appears inside `check()`, so is set to `0` each call... but then the version of `count` inside `check()`'s scope is never incremented. One possibility for a better factoring of functionality: (1) Do all `input()` and printing inside your `main()`; (2) Make `check()` a simpler function that just takes all the info it needs (including past-history of guesses) & reports back.

Comment: @Barmar Ohh, that makes sense. How exactly would I make count increase by 1 after very attempt at guessing a letter and have a limit of 5 attempts?

Comment: @gojomo How would I increment it? I am really new to this as you can probably tell

Comment: Well, you find a spot in your code that's after each guess, & do something like `count = count + 1`, but also make sure `count` variable, or its value, remains somewhere is available to later decision-making code (either some shared variable scope, or passed out as a return value, or poked into a shared object). But beyond that hint, the best way to get it working, & understand how to do these things, is to keep trying alternate things that seem to be slightly better than whatever you have that isn't working. (Simply receiving working code here may short-circuit your own process of discovery.)

Answer (score 0):

For starters `while not guessed:` will continue until guessed is true -> the word was guessed. Next if you want there to be 5 guesses then an answer guess you want to do `for i in range(0, 5):` then run your guess logic replacing

```
if result == word:
    guessed = True
```

with

```
if result == word:
    guessed = true
    break
```

to break out of the loop on a correct guess. Then to allow a guess afterwards, outside of the loop, check if already guessed and allow a guess if not.

Also as a side note you should check that they enter one character with something like

```
guess = input(text)
while len(guess) != 1:
    guess = input(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to mostly keep your original code and trail of thought. The main changes I made was getting rid of the check-function as I felt it didn't do anything too useful. I also changed the guessed-variable into a list, and utilized it's properties for your evaluations.

```
import random

def get_word():
    words = ['cat', 'dog', 'man', 'fox', 'jar']
    return random.choice(words).upper()

def main():
    word = get_word()
    guesses = []
    guessed = False
    print('I am thinking of a 3 letter word with no repeating letters.'
    ' You get five guesses of the letters in my word and then you have'
    ' to guess the word.\n')
    while not guessed and len(guesses)<5:
        text = 'Guess a letter in my word:\n'
        guess = input(text)
        guess = guess.upper()
        if guess in guesses:
            print ('You already guessed "', guess, '"\n')
        elif len(guess) > 1:
            guesses.append(guess)
            if guess == word:
                guessed = True
            else:
                print('No, ', guess, 'is not the word!\n')
        elif len(guess) == 1:
            guesses.append(guess)
            if guess in word:
                print('Yes there is a(n) ', guess, 'in the word!\n')
            else:
                print('No, there is not a(n)', guess, 'in the word!\n')
        else:
            print ('Invalid entry.\n')
    if guessed:
        print ('You correctly guessed the word!\n')
    else:
        correct_guesses = [guess for guess in guesses if guess in word]
        print('Last chance, what is the full word? (HINT: You have'
        'correctly guessed ', str(correct_guesses), ')"')
        fword = input()
        if fword.upper() == word:
            print('You correctly guessed the word!\n')
        else: print('Tough luck! You are out of chances! The correct'
        'word was ', word, '\n')

main()

playing = True
while playing:
    print('Would you like to play again?')
    answ = input()
    if answ.upper() == 'YES':
        main()
    else:
        print('Thank you for playing.')
        playing = False
```